# Books dealing with Lebesgue-Stieltjes rigorously?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, book-recommendation, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

There seem to be a lot of  in stochastic analysis of pathwise Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral generated by the quadratic covariation of two processes, $<M,N>$.

If all our functions are positive, the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral behaves very well. But if the function only has bounded variation, it has a positive and a negative part, we get a signed measure, and it is not clear if this is well defined etc..

So I am wondering, do you know about any books, either in classical real analysis, or books regarding stochastic integration, where this subject is treated with care? When I am reading books I often run into problems with these type of pathwise integrals, because I can not see why everything works out fine, and everything is well defined.

Do you know about any books in either real analysis or stochastic analysis, where they take care of this?

Comment: Maybe it would be more productive if you were to cite a specific part of a proof in a book that you find unsatisfactory?  Otherwise I suspect people may end up suggesting the very same books you object to, because they think they are just fine.

Comment: @NateEldredge For instance in this book: https://books.google.sh/books?id=pZGKC_PVvBsC&printsec=frontcover&dq=editions:ISBN0199215251 in chapter 2 where sotchastic integration wrt. continuous local martingales are built up.  My main problem is pathwise integration wrt. $d[M,N]$, I'd like to see these integrals built up from scratch, and how integrals of the type $\int_0^\infty Xd[M,N]$ are defined. Also if you have a function g of bounded variation call $h(s)=\int_0^s fdg$, and if you then have another function of bounded variation, then $\int_0^s f_2 dh=\int_0^t f_2 f dg$.

Comment: I'd like to see what makes these integrals well-defined, how they are defined, and proved, and also the property above. I don't think it is a problem if everything is positive, but when you have functions that can be positive and negative, I don't see how it all works fine. But in the book above it seems like these properties are used, but I am not sure what they are based on.(And also how you deal with the integrals when the limit is infinity).